# Python: why does my list change after I've retrieved it from an object

Tags: python

Simple question, I've scaled down a problem I'm having where a list which I've retrieve from an object is changing when I append more data to the object. Not to the list.

Can anyone help my understand the behavior of python?

```
class a():
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = []
    def clearLog(self):
        del self.log[:]
    def appendLog(self, info):
        self.log.append(str(info))
    def getLog(self):
        return self.log

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = a()
    obj.appendLog("Hello")

    # get an instance as of this moment....
    list = obj.getLog()
    print list

    obj.appendLog("World")

    # print list, BUT we want the instance that was obtained
    # before the new appendage.   
    print list
```

**OutPut:**

```
['Hello']
['Hello', 'World']
```

Comment: This, I think, is why every developer should learn C, so that this kind of thing is extremely obvious. I'm not an expert on python, so I'll let someone else explain.

Comment: As Matthew Flaschen recommends, don't use `list` as a variable name, use something else, e.g. `L`.

Comment: I think you are not appending data to the object, you're appending data to the list only but inside object..., if you want new object then call constructor again a()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place you create a new list is in the constructor, with the statement:

```
self.log = []
```

Later, when you do:

```
list = obj.getLog()
```

just puts a reference to the same list in a new variable (note, don't use `list`
as a variable name, since it shadows the type).  It does not create or clone a list in any way.  If you want to clone it, do:

```
def getLog(self):
    return list(self.log)
```

You can also use a tuple (read-only sequence), if that's appropriate:

```
def getLog(self):
    return tuple(self.log)
```

This may help minimize confusion about which should be modified.

Comment: Regarding cloning, he could also use `copy.copy(self.log)` or `copy.deepcopy(self.log)` (from the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)) depending on what he wants.

Comment: @Cristian, those are useful tools in general.  But strings are read-only in Python, so there is no reason to use `deepcopy` here.  And of course, using the `list` constructor is simpler than `copy.copy`.

Comment: Yeah, I was only trying to mention other possible solutions for cloning in general. In this specific scenario, `list` or `tuple` seem the best solution to me, too.

Answer (score 4):

When you code

```
`list = obj.getLog()`
```

(ignoring -- just for a second -- what a **terrible** idea it is to use identifiers that shadow builtins!!!) you're saying: "make name `list` refer to exactly the same object that `obj.getLog()` returns" -- which as we know from the code for `class a` is `obj.log`.  So of course since now you have one list object with two names, when you alter that object through **either** name, all alterations will be fully visible from both names, of course -- remember, there *is* just **one** object, you're just using multiple names for it!  You never asked for a copy, so of course Python made no copies.

When you want a copy, instead of the original, **ask for one**!  When you know the type you require (here, a list), the best way is to call the type, i.e.:

```
mylist = list(obj.getLog())
```

This of course becomes impossible if you choose to trample all over the builtins with your identifiers -- -- which is a good part of why such identifier choice is a **BAD** idea (I can't stress that enough: it's hard to think of any worse style choice, to use in your Python coding, than such naming).  So, I've renamed the identifier to `mylist` (and of course you need to rename it in the two `print` statements).

You **could** use highly unreadable or slower approaches to make up for the wanton destruction of the normal functionality of built-in identifier `list`, of course -- e.g.:

```
import copy
list = copy.copy(obj.getLog())   # somewhat slower
```

or

```
list = obj.getLog()[:]           # traditional, but ECCH
```

or

```
temp = obj.getLog()
list = type(temp)(temp)          # abstruse
```

but **BY FAR** the simplest, cleanest, most recommended approach is to **NOT** name your identifiers the same as Python built-ins (it's also a nice idea to avoid naming them just like modules in the standard Python library, for similar though a bit weaker reasons).

Comment: ECCH = European Case Clearing House?! One more reason to hate acronyms.

Comment: Oops, a typo -- I meant "echh" (one C, two Hs), like in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Brand_Ecch ...

Answer (score 1):

Look at this method:

```
def getLog(self):
        return self.log
```

You've returned a reference to self.log and assigned it to list.  Now they both point to the same list on the heap.  When you change self.log, list points to the same location in memory.

You'd have to make a clone and assign that to list for the two to be independent.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed around in Python by reference - Python doesn't make copies for you. The line

```
return self.log
```

returns a reference to the `list` object used internally by `obj`. This means that after the line

```
list = obj.getLog()
```

your `list` variable refers to the *same* object as `obj.log`. To acquire a copy instead, use Python's slice syntax:

```
list = obj.getLog()[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

What this boils down to is that languages like python and ruby try to make it easy for people to refer to arbitrary, complex objects - associative containers of lists of associative containers and such like.  These get too complex to index into repeatedly (and it would be slow), so scripters want to be able to say

```
galleries = world['asia']['japan'][3]['Tokyo']['Galleries']
```

then make queries against *or updates to* the galleries in Tokyo.  That is sometimes convenient (when doing updates), sometimes - as in your case where you think you've made a private copy of some data and want to massage one without affecting the other - very confusing and inconvenient.  But, most scripting languages will adopt this same strategy because to make full independent copies of the data each time would be hideously slow for the common case of just wanting a "handle" through which to inspect some part of the larger data structure.  It's ugly and inconsistent with the way they handle basic types like numbers and textual strings.  As others have said, you need to use:

```
new_list = original_list[:] # slice off a complete copy of a list
new_dictionary = original_dictionary.copy()  # for dictionaries
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that this behavior is specific to scripting languages. It can also happen in Java, C# or even C. A notable exception would be the TCL scripting language. In TCL where you're copying the content of the list most of the time because everything is practically a string. Anyway, the bottom line is that most languages store in a list variable only the address of the list, not its content.